# How to conditionally perform a subtraction based on data in other columns in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset where I am calculating distances between genes. This involves the 'bp.snp' column from one gene's row below being subtracted from the 'bp.snp' column of the current row to give the current row/gene's distance from the next.

However for every start of a new chromosome I do not want the subtraction to be performed, how can I account for this in my for loop?

My data looks like this:

```
Gene  Chromosome  bp.snp  
ACE        1        1   
NOTCH      1        2   
BRCA       1        3   
HER        2       7000 
GABA       2       7001  
P53        3       20000 
APX1       3       20001
```

I want an output column to look this like this:

```
Gene  Chromosome  bp.snp   distance
ACE        1        1         1
NOTCH      1        2         1
BRCA       1        3         0/NA
HER        2       7000       1
GABA       2       7001       0/NA
P53        3       20000      1
APX1       3       20001      1
```

So it ignores performing the bp.snp subtraction with each chromosome change.

My code currently is this:

```
df$distance <- NA
for(i in 1:(nrow(df) - 1)) {
  df$distance[i] = df$bp.snp1[i+1] - df$bp.snp1[i]}
```

I am not sure how to start to essentially ask the code to do 'for every time the Chromosome column increases by 1 do not perform the subtraction in the loop'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ave` and `diff` to *calculate distances* per `Chromosome`.

```
df$distance  <- ave(df$bp.snp, df$Chromosome, FUN=function(x) c(diff(x), NA))
df
#   Gene Chromosome bp.snp distance
#1   ACE          1      1        1
#2 NOTCH          1      2        1
#3  BRCA          1      3       NA
#4   HER          2   7000        1
#5  GABA          2   7001       NA
#6   P53          3  20000        1
#7  APX1          3  20001       NA
```

Or you simply calculate the difference for all and set it to `NA`, on places you have a difference in `Chromosome`.

```
df$distance <- c(diff(df$bp.snp), NA)
df$distance[c(diff(df$Chromosome) > 0, FALSE)]  <- NA
#   Gene Chromosome bp.snp distance
#1   ACE          1      1        1
#2 NOTCH          1      2        1
#3  BRCA          1      3       NA
#4   HER          2   7000        1
#5  GABA          2   7001       NA
#6   P53          3  20000        1
#7  APX1          3  20001       NA
```

Comment: Cool. Did not know ave existed!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  bn.snp is in ascending order:

```
do.call('rbind', lapply(split(df, df$Chromosome), function(x) { x$distance <- c(diff(x$bp.snp), 0); return(x) }))
```

Edit: seems like you want 'distance to next' not 'distance from last'